# Why can't I store the output of a command into a shell variable?

Tags: shell

I'm retrieving an aws parameter store value using aws ssm command. I get the result back. I need to store this value in a shell variable so that I can use it later on.

This on Mac terminal. I am invoking through AWS CLI to get the aws parameters I get the values from aws however I can't set it to a shell variable due to my lack of knowledge of using Shell

```
export PASS=echo "$(aws ssm get-parameters --names "/enterprise/org/dev/spring.datasource.password" --with-decryption --query "Parameters[0].Value" | tr -d '"')"
echo $PASS
```

When I do echo $PASS I expect to see the value of the parameter however I don't get anything. I am sure that the value exist because if I don't export and just run $ aws ssm get-parameters. I see the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to assign the output of your command to the variable is:

```
export PASS=$(aws ssm get-parameters --names "/enterprise/org/dev/spring.datasource.password" --with-decryption --query "Parameters[0].Value" | tr -d '"')
```

The way you are doing it, this is what shell does:

- it sets PASS to "echo"
- it runs the aws command pipeline and interprets the output as a command and tries to run it

Related:

- [How to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/6862601)